# Facebook API add message to SharePhotoContent

Tags: android, facebook

I want to share a picture on Facebook with a description but I only can post an image without description. How can I add a message/description to the photo?

The code I am using to share:

```
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(shareBitmap).build();
    ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    photos.add(photo);

    SharePhotoContent.Builder shareContentBuilder = new SharePhotoContent.Builder();
    shareContentBuilder.addPhotos(photos);
    SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent = shareContentBuilder.build();

    ShareApi.share(sharePhotoContent, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to add `.setCaption("Caption")` to the SharePhoto Builder.

Comment: Hi. I've tried your solution but it's not working anymore.